# python import sqlite error

Tags: python, sqlite

python2.7 and sqlite3 were installed by homebrew on macos 10.8
pysqlite is installed by pip

when I type import sqlite3 in python interapter, it show errors below:

```
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
  Reason: image not found
```

how to correct that error?

Comment: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17312

Comment: On my Mac Python 2.7, pysqlite and Sqlite 3 are installed by default. Couldn't you use those?

Comment: Why do you install a new version of Python when there are already Pyhon 2.7 installed by default ? It is a problem of Homebrew

Comment: @gene: because the Python that comes with OS X is usually a few minor versions behind the latest one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to uninstall both the `sqlite` as well as `python` kegs:

```
brew rm sqlite python
```

and then reinstall Python (which also installs SQLite3 as its dependency):

```
brew install python
```